# Take a Data backup of an existing custom object with attatchments into a new custom object

Tags: administration, data-loader, data

I have a custom object which is part of a managed package and is likely to be discontinued. We want to move all the data in that custom object of the managed package to be transferred to a new custom object along with the notes and attachment.

What is the best way to make sure that i have the correct notes & attachments assigned to records in the new object.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to migrate attachments also, best way is to use "Data Export" option in Salesforce under setup. It will give attachments in separate folders, which can be loaded back using data loader. But if you export attachments using data loader as binary files, you cannot directly load it back.

Also you will have to use VLOOKUP to populate new object record IDs as parent Id to exported attachment data.

Comment: Thanks Victor .. vlookup is probably what i am looking for. Is there any good reference material on this which you have handy? Will google it from my end as well